# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xxx.xx.xx: No digester supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've set up capistrano this way: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04
Using the latest versions of every gem.

What I get when I want to do " `cap production deploy`" is the following:

```
"(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xxx.xx.xx: No digester supplied

Caused by:
No digester supplied

Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)"
```

So I'm quite new in coding and I still need to learn things. Can someone tell me what's going with this message. I couldn't find anything through Google. It's mysterious. If you need more details please let me know.

Comment: run with --trace, and update the question with stack trace

Comment: I got the answer already. I needed to do command: ssh-add on my computer.

Comment: I am having this problem as well, but ssh-add isn't helping

Answer (score 5):

Refresh ssh-agent info:

> eval ssh-agent
>   ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

& then try again

Answer (score 0):

using `ssh-add` will fix the problem as well.